# Change the Site to default theme

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, design

I have changed the look of a Page in my site and the whole site is changed. I want to restore it to the default theme which the company follows. How is it possible to do so?
Thank you

Comment: what exactly did you change in your page?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you said the whole site is changed that means you have changed the `Master page`

**So in this case**, to rollback your `Master page` changes, you should go ahead with one of the below options:

**(1)-** If you have applied your changes to a customized master page, **not** the default master page. so you can just change the master page back to the default one that not changed before like Oslo / Settele as the following:

- In case, it's a `Publishing site`, Go to Site setting > Look and Feel > Master Page > Select your Master Page.

[image]

- In case, it's a `Team site`, check this article [Change the current master page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-current-master-page-49bd29f0-0ddf-4713-a5b5-3455711c9ae0).

**(2)-**  If you have applied your changes to the default master page and you don't take a backup, so in this case, you have two option:

- If you have enabled the `Versions`, you can restore the previous version.

  - Right Click on the master Page > Select `Version History`.
  - Revert the old version.

    [image]
- Else you can set the master page to the site definition.

  - Right Click on the master Page > Select `Reset to Site Definition`.

    [image]

Comment: Thanks for the help but i still cannot figure it out and it is still embarrassing as the version option did not work and the 1st and 3rd  option also as i do not have the permission !
My company has its own branding and i want to apply that to my page rather than the the theme which is currently selected and it is frustrating !